# Unable to fetch subscription from Google play

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, in-app

I have an app where subscription needs to be done I use inapp subscription I have done with upload signed bundle and do internal testing with tester I successfully get the in app product but unable to get subscription I don't know why I use same id for subscription which I give in play store I used in_app_purchase  in flutter don't know why